# TicTacToe code to check the state of the board not working

Tags: python, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I made an algorithm to check whether which player won the game or is it a tie or the game is still not finished yet but it doesn't work well with some testcases.

I don't know what's wrong with my code. but it doesn't work so I think somethings off with my algorithm or the code itself.

so my algorithm basically is:

- separate the moves of player1 and player 2
- check if the moves of player 1 is in the winning moves if it is return 'player1'
- check if the moves of player 2 is in the winning moves if it is return 'player2'
- if there is no winner check if the number of moves is equal to 9. If it is return 'tie'
- else if the number of moves is less than 9 return 'uncertain'

here is the code:

```
def match(a1,a2):
    a1.sort()
    for solution in a2:
        if a1 == solution:
            return True
    return False

def ticTacToeWinner(moves, n):
    # --- Variables ---
    p1 = []
    p2 = []
    winning_moves = [
        [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],
        [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]],
        [[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]],
        [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]],
        [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]],
        [[1,0],[2,1],[3,1]],
        [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],
        [[0,2],[1,1],[2,0]],
    ]

    winner = None
    
    # --- Loops ---
    for i in range(1,n+1): # separate the moves for each player
        if i % 2 == 0:
            p2.append(moves[i-1])
        else:
            p1.append(moves[i-1])

    # --- Conditionals ---
    if len(p1) >= 3: # check if the player1 has more than 3 moves
        if match(p1,winning_moves) == True: # check if the moves of player1 is in the winning moves
            winner = 'player1' # winner is player 1
            return winner

    if len(p2) >= 3: # check if the player2 has more than 3 moves
        if match(p2,winning_moves) == True: # check if the moves of player 2 is in the winning moves
            winner = 'player2' # winner is player 2
            return winner

    if not winner: # there are no winners
        if n == 9: # board is full so it's draw
            return 'draw'
        elif n < 9: # board is not full
            return 'uncertain'
```

This code is my solution for this question:
https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/tic-tac-toe-winner_1214545?topList=top-apple-coding-interview-questions

The code only works for 2 testcases there and incorrect for everything else

Example input and output:

ticTacToeWinner([[0,0],[2,2],[0,1],[1,1],[0,2]],5) -> 'player1'

since the moves of player1 is: [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]] which makes a triple X at the top of the board

The match function at the top is the one that checks whether the move of a player is in the winning moves table.

here is one of the testcases that don't work with the code:

```
5
9
2 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
1 2
0 0
2 1
2 2
0 2
4
1 2
1 0
2 0
1 1
1
2 0
9
2 0
1 2
0 1
0 0
0 2
2 1
2 2
1 1
1 0
3
0 2
2 0
0 0
```

Comment: Here is the interview question link for this algo:
https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/tic-tac-toe-winner_1214545?topList=top-apple-coding-interview-questions

Comment: Please specify exactly where the code goes wrong

Comment: Your code is hard to read for someone who doesn't know it because we don't know what the variables look like. Please at least give an example value for `a1, a2` and `moves, n` in comments above the function definition.

Comment: Also please specify the test cases that don't work, and what the output is, and what you would expect it to be.

Comment: The site requires an account, and an account requires a choice from a closed set of colleges, so no way I am going to create an account. We need all information here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the expected output for the test case you provided?

Answer (score 1):

These are some issues:

- `winning_moves` has a completely wrong row, which also has a 3 -- which is an invalid index.

  Change:

  ```
  [[1,0],[2,1],[3,1]],
  ```

  to:

  ```
  [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]],
  ```
- When `len(p1)` is *greater* than 3, you'll never find a win, because `winning_moves` does not have entries that have this size. Yet it is obvious that there could be a win
- Even when `len(p1)` is *equal* to 3, you may still miss a win, because the order of the moves may not be like they are in `winning_moves`.
- Not a problem, but `elif n < 9` can just be `else`, as there are no other possible values for `n`.

You should really take a different approach: play the moves on a 3x3 board (a 2D list), and then use `winning_moves` to see what is at those winning positions. If it turns out they are all 3 a move of player1, you know that player1 won the game.

So here is what your function should look like:

```
def ticTacToeWinner(moves, n):
    winning_moves = [
        [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],
        [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]],
        [[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]],
        [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]],
        [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]],
        [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]],  # was wrong
        [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],
        [[0,2],[1,1],[2,0]],
    ]

    # create a board:
    board = [
        [".", ".", "."],
        [".", ".", "."],
        [".", ".", "."],
    ]

    # play the moves on the board:
    for i, (row, col) in enumerate(moves):
        board[row][col] = "12"[i % 2]  # store the player's number in this cell
 
    # check who has played on the winning patterns
    for winning_line in winning_moves:
        played = [board[row][col] for row, col in winning_line]
        if played[0] != "." and played[0] == played[1] == played[2]:
            return "player" + played[0]

    if n == 9: # board is full so it's draw
        return 'draw'
    else: # board is not full
        return 'uncertain'
```

Comment: Note that comparison operators such as `==` can be chained in python, as opposed to pretty much every other programming language; `played[1] == played[0] and played[2] == played[0]` can be shortened to `played[0] == played[1] == played[2]`

Comment: Absolutely, @Stef. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that one of your problems is that you don't handle the case of *more* than 3 moves...
I'd advise to change the type of a single "move" to a tuple, which is hashable. then, you'd be able to use this elegant `match` code:

```
def match(player_moves_list: List[tuple], winning_moves:List[List[tuple]]):
    for solution in winning_moves:
        if set(solution).issubset(player_moves):
            return True
    return False
```

to change the list elements to tuple elements, simply turn brackets to parenthesis:

```
winning_moves = [
    [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)],
    ...,
    [(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)],
]
```

Comment: it's still the same as before still not working