# Why can't my python tic tac toe game properly check whether a player has won?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm new with this and I can't figure out how to check if someone has won my tic tac toe game. Some code is in Spanish, I can translate it if you want.

```py
import random

Tablero = [[" ", "|", " ", "|", " "], ["^", "^", "^", "^", "^"], [" ", "|", " ", "|", " "],
           ["^", "^", "^", "^", "^"], [" ", "|", " ", "|", " "]]
turnoAI = False
Relacion_Columnas = {1:-1, 2:0, 3:1}
Finish = False
Count = 0


def DibujarTablero():
    for i in range(len(Tablero)):
        for j in range(len(Tablero[i])):
            print(Tablero[i][j], end="")
        else:
            print("")


def TurnoJugador():
    turnoAI = False
    columna = int(input("Elige la columna: "))
    fila = int(input("Elige la fila: "))
    DibujarCasilla(columna, fila, "X", turnoAI)


def TurnoAI():
    turnoAI = True
    print("Turno de la IA")
    fila = random.randint(1, 3)
    columna = random.randint(1, 3)
    DibujarCasilla(columna, fila, "O", turnoAI)


def DibujarCasilla(columna, fila, char, turnoAI):
    if 0 < columna < 4 and 0 < fila < 4:
        columna_real = columna + Relacion_Columnas[columna]
        fila_real = fila + Relacion_Columnas[fila]
    else:
        print("Casilla no disponible, escoge otra")
        TurnoJugador()

    if Tablero[fila_real][columna_real] == " ":
        Tablero[fila_real][columna_real] = char
        DibujarTablero()
        Finish = CheckWin(columna_real, fila_real)
    else:
        if turnoAI:
            TurnoAI()
        else:
            print("Casilla no disponible, escoge otra")
            TurnoJugador()


def CheckWin(columna, fila):
    for i in range(0, 5, 2):
        try:
            if str(Tablero[columna +i][fila]) == str(Tablero[columna - 2 + i][fila]) and str(Tablero[columna - 2 + i][fila]) == str(Tablero[columna - 4 + i][fila]):
                print(i)
                print(fila)
                print("Finish")
                return True
        except:
            continue

DibujarTablero()
while not Finish:
    TurnoJugador()
    TurnoAI()
```

"Finish" gets printed when it shouldn't and doesn't get printed when it should. I don't know how I can make this in a better way.

Comment: You haven't told anyone what's wrong at all, so what are we looking for?

Comment: Yeah and translating code to english would be both helpful and muy bien practice in general

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your `CheckWin` function:

1. You have swapped rows and columns when using them as indices.
2. These indices can become negative, but that will not trigger an exception, but counts cells from right to left, so -1 is the last entry in the list, ...etc.
3. The loop checks three possible lines, but this cannot be right: the center position in the board can be part of 4 different winning lines.

To be honest, you could have found this out yourself. A decent debugger can help you find such errors as you step through the code, set break points and inspect variables.

An unrelated error is how you set `finish`. This is a global name, so you should declare in your function that you are going to use that global name:

```
global finish
```

I didn't check more, as these problems just mean you have to completely rewrite the `CheckWin` function. Suggestion: don't try to find the winning lines *relative to the last move*. Instead just check all 6 possible lines (3 horizontal, 3 vertical, 2 diagonal).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935430/tictactoe-code-to-check-the-state-of-the-board-not-working/68936299#68936299) is an answer that has code to check for a winner in a 3x3 board.

Comment: Thank you, Im new at this and also in stackoverflow so I aprecciate your advice